# gulp command(gulp webpackNoWatch -–openssl-legacy-provider) enter manually each time in package manager console

Tags: c#, vue.js

I have to constantly enter the following command in the package manager console terminal. If you copy and paste, the gulp command won't execute. I mentioned the error message above. Could someone please explain how to fix this without entering commands in the package manager console terminal?

Alternatively, is there any possibility to add it as a file in the package manager console terminal?

```
gulp webpackNoWatch -–openssl-legacy-provider
```